# 3D "overlay" in Qt Quick 3D

Tags: qt, qtquick3d

I'm porting a three.js app to QML / Qt Quick 3D.

I have the following section to draw certain things (3D objects) "on top" of everything, i.e. disregarding depth order (`this` is a `THREE.Object3D`):

```
if(overlay) {
    this.renderOrder = 999; // render last
    this.material.depthTest = false; // skip depth test
    this.material.depthWrite = false; // don't write to depth
    this.onBeforeRender = function (renderer) {
        renderer.clearDepth(); // clear depth before render
    };
}
```

How can the same achieved in Qt Quick 3D?

Edit: there is a [`depthTestEnabled`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick3d-sceneenvironment.html#depthTestEnabled-prop) property but that toggles depth testing globally, not just for a single Node.

Answer (score 0):

QtQuick 3D is part of QtQuick and the 3D scene is rendered withing the SceneGraph. This means if you want to create an "overlay" you just need to create any QML Item that is on higher z-order than your 3D scene (not part of the scene nodes but the parent QML Item) and it will be rendered on top of everything.

Comment: so by adding another `View3D` on top of the current one, and “cloning” the camera? I thought of doing that but it seemed a waste of resources, just to disable depth test for one 3D node….

Comment: No, just add any kind of "normal" 2D QML Item on top of the View3D.

Comment: Perhaps I didn’t explain it good enough: what I want to do is draw a 3D item (e.g. a cube) into its position in the existing scene, but with depth test disabled, so that it is drawn entirely even if it is fully or partially behind other objects.